# Manipulating the Text selection in Powerpoint

Tags: c#, hyperlink, powerpoint

I was just trying to do some coding on highlighting a portion of text in PowerPoint so that I could insert a hyperlink to it. I could achieve it without any difficulty in Powerpoint 2003 and to my surprise, it did not work in PowerPoint 2007... The code that I used is as follows :

```
((PowerPoint.Application)applicationObject).ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Text = "PPT";
((PowerPoint.Application)applicationObject).ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Select();
((PowerPoint.Application)applicationObject).ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.ActionSettings[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address = "http://www.google.com";
((PowerPoint.Application)applicationObject).ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect();
```

Can anyone tell me what could have gone wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the Action of the ActionSetting instance to HyperLink e.g. in your sample:

`((PowerPoint.Application)applicationObject).ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.ActionSettings[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Action = PpActionType.ppActionHyperlink;`

Answer (score 0):

You should save  your ppt app like an app with macro's, if it ends on 'x' (like pptx) you cannot run macros.

So save as sth with macro support like ppsm, pptm,
(use save as)

see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa433259.aspx

Comment: No peter i tried that too its not working :( ...the same code is working in 2003 but why not in 2007...pls can anyone help me sort this..

Comment: Anyone there to throw light on this :(